# How to map over an array and generate an object istead of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I would like that this code:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var result = arr.map((i) => ([i.key]: i.val)); //something like this

console.log(result);
```

Returns:

```
{foo: 'bar', hello: 'world'}
```

Is this possible in ECMA6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method is using to generate a new array. To reduce into a single object use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var arr = [{
    key: 'foo',
    val: 'bar'
  },
  {
    key: 'hello',
    val: 'world'
  }
];

// define the property and return the object reference
// where define the initial value as an empty object for result
var result = arr.reduce((obj, o) => (obj[o.key] = o.val, obj), {}); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It says ther is a syntax error in your snippet.

Comment: @WasteD : I think your browser not supports ES6 arrow function

Comment: Might be the problem ty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `forEach` method:

```js
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var obj = {};
arr.forEach(function(item){
  obj[item.key] = item.val;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
arr.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.key] = obj.val;
    return map;
}, {});
```